# Why am I getting a validation error even though I'm providing data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, mongoose, postman

For some reason, the backend of my app doesn't think I'm providing data, even though I am, while testing my routes.

I've looked around, but I haven't found anything that quite matches up to the problem I'm having.

I've been trying to build the backend for my app by following this tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q

Before I added validation to my models, I received 200s and 201s for my HTTP requests. Once I added validation, I began receiving error messages informing me that I'm not providing the necessary information, even though I am.

I'm using Mongoose 5.5.8, Cors 2.8.5, Body-Parser 1.19.0, and Postman 7.1.1.

I've tried using the .exec() method once, but that only gave me a worse error.

Here is my model:

```
const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  first_name: { type: String, required: true },
  last_name: { type: String, required: true },
  preferred_name: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);
```

Here is my controller:

```
  add_student: (req, res) => {
    const student = new Student({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      preferred_name: req.body.preferred_name
    });
    student
      .save()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Student added!",
          createdStudent: {
            first_name: result.first_name,
            last_name: result.last_name,
            preferred_name: result.preferred_name
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(422).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
  },
```

Here is my route:

```
router.route("/")
  .post(studentController.add_student)
```

And here is the data I'm trying to pass through Postman:

```
{
"first_name": "Steve",
"last_name": "Jones",
"preferred_name": "Stevie Boy"
}
```

As you can see, I am passing data, but I keep getting errors as if there's no information there at all.

I guess I need to know how to properly provide pass data through my controller, so my app doesn't think I'm trying to pass an empty object.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also why deal with the `_id` mongoDb would create one for you automatically. Not need to define `_id` in your schema.

Comment: The error I'm getting is the 422 (unprocessable entity) I have hardcoded into my controller.  (When I tried using the .exec() method it threw a 500) And I defined the _id because that's what the guy does in the tutorial I've been following along with. It's a shopping cart app with several connected documents in the database, and I thought that's what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was a user (me) error. In Postman, [image: Screen grab of my Postman GUI]

Where it says JSON (application/json), I had it said to text. Setting it to JSON fixed my problem.

And have no doubts, I feel plenty foolish about this!